# How to build () => x.prop lambda expression dynamically?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda, queryover

I have code like

```
DepartmentPaperConsumption dto = null;
```

then later i have NHibernate QueryOver result, and i want to order it

```
result.OrderByAlias(() => dto.TotalColorCopys);
```

but I want to be able to specify any property of `dto` dynamicly with string.
I tryed using [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) but is seems that I just can't get it.
I also tried building LambdaExpression from ground up - also without luck.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Would you mind posting the signature of the `OrderbyAlias` method?

Comment: if it helps QueryOverOrderBuilder<TRoot, TSubType> OrderByAlias(Expression<Func<object>> path)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see how to construct the lambda [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/233505#233505), but it really is pretty simple in your case:

```
var arg = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DepartmentPaperConsumption));
var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, propertyName),
    typeof(object));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(body);
```

The tricky thing is invoking the `OrderByAlias` - using `MakeGenericMethod` may be the way, as shown in the link above.

Comment: That can't possibly be the Expression<delegate-type> the OP wants.

Comment: @Ani - OK, I will fix that. Not having the signature doesn't help ;p

Comment: @Ani - any better for you now?

Comment: +1. Ah, now we are closer, but it's hard to proceed without knowing more about OrderByAlias (signature, overloads etc). I wanted to post something similar, but I'm hesitant because I think there's some funky stuff going on.  http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx

Comment: Marc, the OP has posted the signature. I think you might be done with just a `Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.TypeAs(body, typeof(object)), null)`. Not sure though, I think there's more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: @Ani - I would imagine it'll need explicit convert - will add

Comment: @Ani your version throws Cannot interpret member from (null.TotalPages As Object)

Comment: As I mention, I think there's something strange here (from briefly looking at the QueryOver page), so this obvious approach may not work. I get the feeling it *wants* a closure so it can extract the name of the member of the *closure* class (the captured variable - `dto` in your example). No?

Comment: @Ani yes it cares only for name of prop

Comment: i still would want something like Expression.FromString("() => x.y") from Microsoft :) I think it's not trivial at all, but that would simplify my life :)

Answer (score 3):

well use dynamic linq as you wrote, or use expression tree
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

i don't think that there are other solutions

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find one way myself, but it looks more of workaround, Marc's version is way more simpler. I will accept Marc's answer as soon as i will test it. Heres my workaround :

```
public class MemberModifier : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)
    {
        return Visit(expression);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var t = typeof (DepartmentPaperConsumption);
        var memberInfo = t.GetMember("TotalPages")[0];
        return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(node.Expression, memberInfo);
    }
}
```

and then in code

```
        Expression<Func<object>> exp = () => dto.TotalColorPrints;
        var mod = new MemberModifier();
        var modEx = mod.Modify(exp);
        result.OrderByAlias((Expression<Func<object>>)modEx)
```

MemberModifier is only raw prototype, it should be more generic and not depend on DepartmentConsumption and without hardcoded "TotalPages"